# Bonsai ficus has brown spots on leaves -- how do I diagnose and cure?

Tags: plant-health, bonsai, ficus

My ficus bonsai has these brown spots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

It's only a few leaves, but obviously I want to get ahead of it. Preliminary Googlage says that this can be caused by bacteria or fungi or insects: how can I tell which it is, so I can treat the problem correctly?

Comment: How is your drainage? Are the pot and the soils well drained?

Comment: @benn Looks OK to me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like insect or fungi damage, you could prune the bad leaves off then spray the rest of the leaves with any kind of leave spray or homemade dish soap + water mix. If you use a homemade solution, spray top and bottom of the leaves and let it sit on the leaves for a few mins then spray it with water to wash it off, once a week until everything looks good.